# How to Convert Date Object with Format "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt" to DateObject with Format "dd/MM/yy

Tags: c#, date, format

I have googled alot and tried lot of solutions but nothing is working for me.For Ex i Have tried below :

```
public static DateTime ParseDateToSystemFormat(DateTime date)
{
  IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB", true);

  DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                                    "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                    culture,DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
  return Convert.ToDateTime(dt,culture);

}
```

If anyone have solved this please let me know.

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve. As the answers point out, there is no formatting attached to a `DateTime` object. Your problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: DateTime object doesn't have format. You can print this object in format you want.

Comment: this really would only make sense if this operation would return a string

Answer (score 3):

Date objects do not have formatting associated to them - you only use formatting for display.

When it is time to display the `DateTime` object, use either [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) or [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) format strings to format the display to your liking.

What you are doing here:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                                "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                culture,DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
```

Is rather strange - you are getting a specific string representation of your `DateTime` - `date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`, then parsing that string back to a `DateTime` object. A bit of a long way to say `DateTime dt = date;`, with clearing out the hours/minutes/seconds data.

If you simply want the date portion of a `DateTime`, use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property. It produces:

> A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).

Answer (score 2):

The internal representation of a `DateTime` is always the same. There is no formatting attached to a `DateTime` object.

If it is only a display problem, then convert the `DateTime` to a string and display that string. You already know how to do it: Using `ToString` and specifying the format you want to have.